# How to write this sentence formally

Tags: linear-algebra, formal-grammar

I have this sentence

- **Prediction** is a numerical value, $P_{a,j}$, expressing the predicted likeliness of item $i_{j} \notin I_{u_{a}}$ for the active user $u_a$. This predicted value is within the same scale (e.g., from $1$ to $5)$ as the opinion values provided by $u_{a}$

I want to write the Pa,i (the prediction of a user a on an item i) formally.

because P is a rating, thus P belongs to the group ratings.

```
Rating = {0,1,2,3,4,5}

P belong-to-group-symbol Rating
```

I also know that `a` belongs to Users. Thus.

```
U = {u1, u2, .... um}
a belong-to-group-sybmo U
```

and I know that `i` belongs to Items. Thus,

```
I = {i1, i2, .... in}
i belong-to-group-symbol I
```

#### my question

is how can I say that P belongs to Rating, and at the same time say that P is a relationship between `a` (user) and `i` (item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R$ be the space of ratings, $U$ the space of users and $I$ the space of items. Then, $P:U \times I \to R$ is a function that takes elements $(a,i) \in U \times I$ into an element of $R$.

Comment: Okay that is close, but not 100 % what I wanted, because I am seeking a just math solutions. so I can't say `function`, `element` ... I've done that a lot before when i was at school, but now i forgot how

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli $P_{a,i}:U \times I \to R$. That is it. The words are just to explain what the notation means, but for someone who understands the notation just that is enough.

Comment: okay, actually, `i` belongs to `I` except a small group of `I` called `H`, then can I say P: U X I/H ----> R ?

Comment: $P : U \times (I \setminus H) \to R$.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Sure. I think it is clearer with a parenthesis: $P:U \times (I \setminus H) \to R$.